# How to nest in Sass a header that is inside of an element with a class?

Tags: css, sass

## Question

What is the difference between `.center h1{ }` and `h1.center` and how does this affect what styling results, what should be taken into consideration when nesting?

```
 .center {
     text-align: left;
 }
 .center h1 {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Sass is nothing but just a way to write css faster. Since, we can't use dynamic variables in css, some frustrated developers created script using their favorite language (ruby) which let us inject variables in css. Thus, they named it as SASS. I hope I am not confusing you. :)

Comment: The descendant combinator is plain CSS. You aren't using any SASS features in that code. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators

Answer (score 2):

The second rule styles all `h1` inside `.center`, not just direct children. For example:

```
<div class="center">
    <h1>this one</h1>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="another div">      
        <h1>this one</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's normal CSS, not SASS syntax (but it's alowed in SASS too).

In SASS it should be:

```
.center {
    text-align: left;

    h1 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: "In SASS it should be:" <- No, it "shouldn't" be anything.  Sass does not require nesting at all, it is purely a convenience for the author.  SCSS syntax is a subset of CSS.  If it is valid CSS, it is valid SCSS.

Comment: @cimmanon: please read once again what I wrote. _it's normal CSS, not SASS syntax (allowed in SASS too)_. It means, that you can save your file as `.sass`, process it as SASS and ignore SASS/LESS/preprocessor advantages. If you want to find a reason for downvote correct answers, you'll find it everywhere.

Comment: I'm taking issue with the fact that you're claiming that you're "supposed" to write selectors in Sass by using nesting, which is completely wrong: nesting is completely optional.  Also, you can't compile SCSS syntax using the `.sass` extension.

Answer (score 0):

The second selector has nothing to do with center function. It merely gives every h1 in an element with a 'center' class a margin on the bottom, which is 10px.